# Foreign key constraints with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following 3 tables

```
╔═════════════════╗
║   proj          ║
╠═════════════════╣
║ id              ║
║ name            ║
║ companyID       ║
║ departmentID    ║
╚═════════════════╝

╔══════════════╗
║   comapany   ║
╠══════════════╣
║ id           ║
║ companyname  ║
║ ..........   ║
║ ..........   ║
║ etc...       ║
╚══════════════╝

╔═══════════════╗
║   Department  ║
╠═══════════════╣
║ id            ║
║ companyID     ║
║ zip           ║
║ etc...        ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

I have a foreign key constraint with project tables `<companyID>` and company tables `<id>`. Also have another foreign key constraint with Department tables `<companyID>` and company tables `<id>`.

I am just curious to know if could make a FK constraint in Project Table, so that while adding data in project table, after selecting client, only that client specific department will be loaded.

Comment: FK's are for data integrity. They are not meant for filters in views if that is what you mean. Please clarify much better what you are asking as it is very unclear.

Comment: Fyi: If you have in your `proj` table constraint to `department` table - you able insert as value to `proj.departmentID` ony values that present in `Department.id`.